# ng-table data not showing on page load

Tags: angularjs, ngtable, mean.io

I have integrated ngTable into my mean.io stack and I'm having trouble with populating the table on page load.  If I select one of the column headers, the data shows up and the table works as advertised.

Here is my html

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
    <tbody ng-repeat="p in $data">
    <tr id="tr{{p._id}}" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
        <td class="rowTd" data-title="'Task Code'"   sortable="'task_code'">{{p.task_code}}</td>
        <td class="rowTd" data-title="'Task Name'"    sortable="'task_name'">{{p.task_name}}</td>
        <td class="rowTd" ><input type=button id="editRowBtn{{p._id}}" value="edit"
                                  ng-click="setEditId(p._id)"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-show="editId===p._id" ng-if="editId===p._id">
        <td colspan="7" ng-include src="'editRow.html'"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my controller code.

```
    var data = GeneralTasks.query();

    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,
        count: 10
    },{
        total: data.length,
        getData: function($defer, params) {
            params.total(data.length);
            $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
        }
    });

    $scope.editId = -1;

    $scope.setEditId =  function(pid) {
        $scope.editId = pid;
    };
```

I am new to using this table so i'm sure there is something i'm overlooking.

Comment: What does `GeneralTasks.query()` return: a promise or an array of data?

Comment: It returns the data array.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to provide the answer to my question so it may help others.  Anytime an item in the table is added or removed, the table must be reloaded.  Since $save and $remove invoke a callback function, just inserted the following for updating the table.

```
    $scope.add = function() {
        if (!$scope.tasks) $scope.tasks = [];

        var task = new GeneralTasks({
            task_code: $scope.task_code,
            trade: $scope.trade,
            task: $scope.task,
            task_name: $scope.task_name
        });

        task.$save(function(response) {
            $scope.tasks.push(response);

            var data = $scope.tasks;
            $scope.tableParams.total(data.length);
            $scope.tableParams.reload();
        });

        this.task_code = this.trade = this.task = this.task_name = '';
    };
```

First i update the $scope list with the response and then update the tables data and length.  Then just call reload.

As I've stated earlier, i do this for $save and $remove.  Here is the $remove code.

```
    $scope.remove = function(task) {
        for (var i in $scope.tasks) {
            if ($scope.tasks[i] === task) {
                $scope.tasks.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }

        task.$remove();
        var data = $scope.tasks;
        $scope.tableParams.total(data.length);
        $scope.tableParams.reload();
    };
```

I have noticed that when I edit a name in the list and then cancel, the name does not reset.  I suppose I should add similar code for the cancel action but I'm lazy and that's the least of my worries for now.  :)

Hope this helps someone else.